# Magic with publishing section in artifactoryPublish configuration

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory, publishing, maven-publish

I faced some magic behaviour in build.gradle configuration.
I'm trying to enable artifactoryPublish for project with subprojects.
I have the following structure
root
--subproj1
--subproj2
--common

gradle version 6.0.1

## Case 1

on root level i have build gradle file with the following section

```
subprojects {
    apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/artifactory.gradle"
}
```

in artifactory.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }

artifactory {
    contextUrl = artifactoryUrl
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'mvn-snapshot-local'
            password = artifactoryPassword
            username = artifactoryUser
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

when i run artifactoryPublish it complete successfully but publish nothing

## Case 2

when i move publishing section from file to top level like this

```
subprojects {
    apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/artifactory.gradle"
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}
```

everithing works fine, build successfull and publish.

## Question

What is the difference in this 2 configurations, why it's not working in the 1 case? 
I think would look more accurate if i keep all publishing related sections in one place rather then in different, but i can't by some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was that I missed plugin configuration:

```
    pluginManagement {
    gradle.ext.artifactoryPassword = artifactory_password ?: "nokey"
    gradle.ext.artifactoryUser = artifactory_user ?: "nokey"
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryUrl}/mvn-gradle-plugins"
            credentials {
                username = gradle.ext.artifactoryUser
                password = gradle.ext.artifactoryPassword
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryUrl}/mvn-libs-release"
            credentials {
                username = gradle.ext.artifactoryUser
                password = gradle.ext.artifactoryPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The repositories were configured in repositories section:

```
    repositories {
    if(version.toString().endsWith('SNAPSHOT')) {
        maven {
            url "$artifactoryUrl/mvn-libs-snapshot"
            credentials {
                username artifactoryUser
                password artifactoryPassword
            }
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "$artifactoryUrl/mvn-libs-release"
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUser
            password artifactoryPassword
        }
    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            password = artifactoryPassword
            username = artifactoryUser
        }
        url "$artifactoryUrl/mvn-external"
    }
    mavenLocal()
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

But it hasn't worked until I added plugin management section and updated versions of artifactory and recon plugins.